# flutter dynamic height space used ConstrainedBox

Tags: flutter, dynamic, height

I would like to make a space dynamic height depends on screen height by a constrainedBox. But if I don't set child or let child is a sizedBox, height is minHeight and if let child is a container minHeight was taken. The height is not dynamic by screen. So what can I do? Thank for your help!

```
                  ConstrainedBox(
                      child: Container(
                      ),
                        constraints:
                            BoxConstraints(
                              minWidth: double.infinity,
                              maxHeight: 100, minHeight: 30)),
```

Answer (score 0):

`maxHeight` only works if the space was needed

you can try something like `height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.3` for 30% height

or Expanded with flex, is the same like %

```
                  new Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Expanded(
                        flex: 2,
                        child: new Container()
                      ),
                      new Expanded(
                          flex: 1,
                          child: new Container()
                      ),
                    ]
                  )
```

here a code with screen size >600 and BoxConstraints
then ist 30 + 5% otherwise only 30

```
         ConstrainedBox(
              child: Container(
              ),
              constraints:
                  BoxConstraints(
                      minWidth: double.infinity,
                      maxHeight: 100, minHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height > 600 ? 30 + MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.05 : 30)),
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I also tried it before. But use percent of height screen is not optimize as my expectation. So I have to check for example screen height > 600 or not. It's okay but it's hard coding. I wanna find a dynamic solution with ConstrainedBox.

Comment: i add another example, only when >600 and then 30 + 5%